# Real series convergence check

Tags: convergence-divergence, matlab

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n! \> x^n}{(x+1)(2x+1) \cdots (nx+1)}
$$

I start with d'Alembert, $\displaystyle L= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ it gives me: $L=x+1$, to find convergence directly ($L<1$) we need $x<0$.

For $x>0$ the serie is not convergent because would be $L>1$.

Finally I try: $x=0 \Rightarrow L=1$. So There we have two ways:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1 \ or \ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

For $\displaystyle x=0 \Rightarrow \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ (The criteria does not decide, so I can apply Raabe:

I apply Raabe $\displaystyle (n(1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})$ i get the limit is $-\infty$ (It's less than 1), and as Raabe says the serie do not converges at $x=0$

I am right? Someone could check the solution with a math software or something, I do not know how to use matlab or mathematica.

Thanks in advance, Gabriel.

P.D. Sorry for the first edit, I am new at LaTeX and I did not have time enough to explain the exercise clearly.

Comment: As sinbadh said, you may want to include how you arrive at the limit in the Raabe test.

Comment: I edited the ex. could someone have a quick look?

Comment: I meant: how do you evaluate the expression in the Raabe test in order to arrive at $-\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

How are you applying Rabee's criteria?

First of all, for $x=0$ clearly the series converges.

Now, for $x\neq 0$, $\dfrac{\frac{n!x^{n}}{(x+1)(2x+1)...(nx+1)}}{\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{(x+1)(2x+1)...((n+1)x+1)}}=\dfrac{(n+1)x+1}{(n+1)x}=1+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)x}$

If $x>0$, by Rabee's criteria, $n\left(\left(1+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)x}\right)-1\right)=\dfrac{n}{(n+1)x}\to \dfrac{1}{x}$. Then, if $0<x<1$, also series is convergent.

Analyse the case $x<0$.

Comment: You may have accidentally exchanged $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ in Raabe's criterion.

Comment: @Justpassingby you're right. I edited the message. Thanks

Comment: still not 100% correct. You should not start from the d'Alembert quotient but from its inverse.

Comment: @Justpassingby But i'm starting from inverse of d'Alambert quotient

Comment: OK but the second equality introduces a mysterious term +1 in the denominator.

Comment: @Justpassingy thanks again. In Mexico is 7:23 am, and I could not sleep all night.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33812/discussion-between-sinbadh-and-justpassingby).

Comment: Why fo $x=0$ the serie clearly converges? And as @Justpasssingby says what about that +1?

Comment: for $x=0$ numerator of all the summands are 0 and denominator are 1. On the other hand, @Justpassingby talked about a pair of type errors in my proof, but I corrected them.

Comment: @sinbadh Your current proof is modest because it solves more cases than just $0<x<1.$ As to the case $x=1$, it is not directly covered by your analysis but it can be verified to diverge directly.